# Is it possible to detect that an impending shutdown (or reboot) is in progress?

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script, shutdown, uptime

I'm trying to write a script in bash that I intend to start on system startup and end on system shutdown. The idea is to create a system uptime tracker for myself.

For the purpose, I want to save the uptime of each day in a file. But I can't figure out a way to know when a shutdown has been triggered by the user (or by the system). This is very important because otherwise I won't be able to save the session end time in the file.

Also it could have been done by running a loop after some x amount of time and saving the current uptime. But I think it's inefficient and at the same time will perform unnecessary disk operations.

There might be readymade solutions available for this (or perhaps a native command), but I want to code it myself.

Comment: it should be possible to make your service have a shutdown function that gets called when the system is going down. However, there's always the chance of the system going down unexpectedly, e.g. due to a power-out. That might also include an unknown amount of time spent shut down, before the system starts up again. So, you'll have to prepare for doing some cleanup every time the system starts up, and if you want to save the uptime before a sudden shutdown, you'll have to log it in advance. Just write the uptime to a log every hour or so, it's not much disk traffic.

Comment: @ilkkachu Thanks. How to write the shutdown function? This solution sounds good to me.

Answer (score 1):

You can get most of this information from checking log files, rather than installing a script.  If you did want to directly run a script at shutdown / reboot, you can install a (depending on your system) systemd script or an init script.  Actually, installing a script to measure shutdown / startup events won't cover crashes, you'd still have to check logs.

The file `/var/log/wtmp` logs reboots, logging an event near the end of each boot.  The `last` command interprets this file, and by default displays the time between boots (but not the uptime between boots).  However, this doesn't log shutdowns.  It would be possible to add a script to add a wtmp entry to log shutdowns in wtmp too.

To cover crashes, you'd have to look at each reboot time, and then find the `/var/log/syslog*` file that had the reboot time, and then backtrack to the first entry before the boot started and check the time on that.

It appears the tuptime package does most this and may be what you want.

Comment: Another option is [uptimed](https://github.com/rpodgorny/uptimed).

Comment: `last` knows the pseudo-user `reboot`, so `last -R --time-format iso reboot` is possible.

Comment: The issue is that the reboot entry dropped into wtmp that last sees has a timestamp slightly in the middle of the next boot.  It doesn't have an entry for shutdown.  So you can see when it booted, but not when it shut down or crashed using wtmp alone.  Things like tuptime makes an attempt to log shutdown and crash as well, although it is possible to scrape estimates from syslog without those.